# Weblogic + Change deployment order via command

Tags: ant, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am using ant script to undeploy and deploy the application to weblogic server. For a particular application I want to setup the "Deployment Order" a different value. Is there any way I can mention the deployment order via ANT. Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weblogic.Deployer utility and its ANT version wldeploy do not provide a feature to set the Deployment Order while deploying the Application.

The order can only be updated after the deployment. You can still automate it with WLST if that's what you're looking for. Here is an example: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1014169