# How to specify deployment order of war file for weblogic server?

Tags: weblogic12c

Is there a way to specify the deployment order in the deployment description of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible to set the deployment order at the application level. Only [WLST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722899/weblogic-change-deployment-order-via-command) or the admin console enables you to set this value.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a file deployment_order.py and run it using the command

```
wlst deployment_order.py
```

below are the contents of wlst file

```
connect('<adminuser>','<adminpassword>','t3://<adminurl>:<port>')
edit()
startEdit()
cd('AppDeployments/<appname>')
set('DeploymentOrder',200)
save()
activate()
```